# 'No Rakefile found' error from the 'cap install' command

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to convert an old project from cap2 to cap3. After deleting the old Capfile, running `cap install` gives me:

```
$ cap install
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: capfile, Capfile, capfile.rb, Capfile.rb, /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/Capfile)
/usr/bin/cap:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

isn't the install command meant to create the `Capfile`?

I get the same error if I run the `cap install` command on a new project (= empty folder).

I'm using version 3.4.0.

Comment: Have you tried it with bundle exec before it?

Comment: This is not a ruby project (I installed the debian capistrano package). I was hoping to avoid having to setup bundler, a Gemfile and specific version of Ruby just to get this up and running, but I'll give that a go.

Comment: I avoid distro provided repackaging of Ruby gems, because they don't always work, and are rarely updated. I would suggest using Bundler and Ruby directly, otherwise I have no idea how to help with this.

Answer (score 4):

I setup a test environment and re-produced the error:

```
$ cap install
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: capfile, Capfile, capfile.rb,  Capfile.rb, /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/Capfile)
/usr/bin/cap:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

$ cap --trace install
cap aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: capfile, Capfile, capfile.rb,  Capfile.rb, /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/Capfile)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:684:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/usr/bin/cap:3:in `<main>'
```

Located `Capfile` and ran the command

```
$ cap --rakefile /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/templates/Capfile install
mkdir -p config/deploy
create config/deploy.rb
create config/deploy/staging.rb
create config/deploy/production.rb
mkdir -p lib/capistrano/tasks
create Capfile
Capified
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my capistrano used to work fine, but something happened. I believe i updated my ruby in some moment and the capistrano stopped to work. So when i ran `cap install` the result was:

[image]

So i discovered that the Capfile changed directory, from **/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/Capfile** to **/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/templates/Capfile**. So to work i used the command `cap --rakefile /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/templates/Capfile install` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Ruby & Capistrano for debian package then the Capfile can be now found in directory **/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/templates/Capfile.** So use the command **cap --rakefile /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/templates/Capfile install** indicating the right path to Capfile.

Answer (score 0):

$ rbenv rehash

Since I am using rbenv, the above command worked for me!